# How to get the output of the current PHP?

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo 'Hello';
echo 'World':

$e = // Get the output of the page.

echo $e; // 'HelloWorld' should be printed.
?>
```

I want to get all the output of the current page and print it as a variable.

For example, I printed 'Hello' and 'World' respectively. How can I get the content on the page?

Comment: It is possible to do this, but it is not particularly advisable. _Why_ do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use Output Buffering:

```
ob_start();
echo 'Hello';
echo 'World':

$e = ob_get_clean();

echo $e; // 'HelloWorld' should be printed.
```

More information can be found in the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: Worth noting that this assumes that output buffering is not already enabled, or that the buffer is empty beforehand. YMMV depending on buffering settings and application state.